# link inside scheme doesn't work

Tags: mxgraph

i include [this](http:////www.draw.io/js/embed-static.min.js) script on the my site (and all work fine), but now i have js error in console[image]

when i click on the link inside scheme
i think problem in this line

`var d = a.view.graph.isBlankLink(b) ? a.view.graph.linkTarget : "_top";`

any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: kk, and what i should do?

Comment: when will the release?